# How to prove an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}_{\Vert} + \mathbf{z}_{\perp}$, given a fixed vector $\mathbf{u}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we fix a vector $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it can be written as $$\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}_{\Vert} + \mathbf{z}_{\perp}$$
where $\mathbf{z}_{\Vert}$ is a vector parallel to $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ is a vector orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$.

But how to prove this rigorously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are allowed to globally parallel transport in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can assume that $u,z$ are based at the same point $p$. Even more, we can allow $p = \textbf{0}$ i.e in some plane you have this image,

[image]

where $b =u $ and $z = a$. Define the projection of $z$ onto $u$ as,

$$\textbf{proj}_u z = \frac{\langle u, z \rangle }{\|u\|^2} \ u$$

Then it follows that $\{e_1=\textbf{proj}_u z, e_2=z- \textbf{proj}_uz\}$ forms an orthogonal basis at $\textbf{0}$ i.e any vector $v$ at $\textbf{0}$ is given by,

$$v = \langle v, e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle v, e_2 \rangle e_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $z_{||} = \frac{\langle u, z \rangle}{||u||^2} u$ and $z_{\perp} = z - z_{||}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\langle z , u \rangle=0$, then you have the decomposition. Else note that $$\langle u,z-\lambda u \rangle=0 \iff\langle z,u \rangle-\lambda\langle u,u \rangle=0$$
Choose $\lambda=\dfrac{\langle z , u \rangle}{\|u\|^2}$. Then $$z=\lambda u+(z-\lambda u)$$

Answer (score 0):

We shall proceed by computing the vectors. First, we consider $\mathbf{u}$ as a column vector in the canonical basis and more specifically as an $n \times 1$ matrix. Also note that we can write the dot product $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ as $\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{y}^T$ is the transpose of $\mathbf{y}$ by identifying the $1 \times 1$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}$.

Now consider the vector $\mathbf{v}=\frac{\mathbf{u}}{||\mathbf{u}||}$ which is the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{u}$. Because it's a unit vector we know $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}=1$. We now construct the $n \times n$ matrix $A = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T$ and proceed by showing that For any vector $\mathbf{z}$ and $I$ the $n \times n$ identity matrix that $A\mathbf{z}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{u}$, $(I-A)\mathbf{z}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{z}$, and their sum is $\mathbf{z}$.

First $A\mathbf{z}= (\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T)\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{z})$ and since $\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z} \cdot \mathbf{u}$ so $A\mathbf{z}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{u}$ and therefore parallel to $\mathbf{u}$.

To see that $(I-A)\mathbf{z}$ is perpendicular to $A\mathbf{z}$ we show that their dot product is zero. First note that $A^T = (\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T)^T=A$ so it is symmetric.

$(A\mathbf{z})^T(I-A)\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}^TA^T(I\mathbf{z}-A\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z}^TA^T\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{z}^TA\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}^TA\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{z}^TA\mathbf{z}=0$

so $A\mathbf{z}$ and $(I-A)A\mathbf{z}$ are orthogonal. All that is left is to show $A\mathbf{z} + (I-A)\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}$ which is trivial and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The one dimensional case is trivial as we let $\mathbf{z}_{\perp} = \mathbf{0}$ and clearly $\mathbf{u}\,\Vert\,\mathbf{z}$.

Let $n>1$. Consider the plane which $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ lie in. Let $\mathbf{u}_{\perp}$ be an arbitrary non-zero vector which is perpendicular to $\mathbf{u}$ in that plane (obviously one must exist).

Any set of two non-parallel and non-zero vectors which lie in a plane form a basis for it. Therefore $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}_{\perp}\}$ form a basis for the plane.

Hence

$$\mathbf{z}=\lambda\mathbf{u}+\mu\mathbf{u}_{\perp}$$

for some $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R$.

Let $\mathbf{z}_{\Vert}=\lambda\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}=\mu\mathbf{u}_{\perp}$.

Then we have found vectors $\mathbf{z}_{\Vert}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ which satisfy the conditions and equation asked for in the question.